# How to find documentation for older versions

Tags: angular

I have decided to first finish my app and then update, since the current rate of releases is way too much for me to keep up to date. I am however finding trouble when searching for documentation, very basic stuff like `import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';` is found with the @ notation which afaik is only for newer versions.

I am working with beta version .8 so where can I find the documentation of how to do, well, anything, in this version? Because it's so weird for me if I have half the app with one syntax for imports, for example, and the other half with the newest one simply because I can't find the older way of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

Well the website code is on Github

https://github.com/angular/angular.io

You could always look for older versions over there

Here is a 2 month old branch you could search in:

https://github.com/angular/angular.io/tree/wardbell-patch-2/public/docs

Comment: And how would I do that? I might be dumb but can't find anything other than latest versions

Comment: Take an older branch and use the search box to look for your stuff https://github.com/angular/angular.io/tree/wardbell-patch-2/public/docs